# bxslider stopping video element autoplay

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video, bxslider

I'm using Bx slider for a standard carousel. One of the slides has a  element with autoplay and loop on to use as a background.

The issue is for some reason bx slider stops the video from playing. Is there a known way to override this behaviour.

The video plays fine when the page is loading until the js for bxslider fires and it stops.

I'm using the out of the box config for bxslider, and inside the li is this:

```
 <video preload="" loop="" autoplay="" class="video-bg">
        <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/tbf/flag.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/tbf/flag.ogv" type="video/ogg">
 </video>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

By using callbacks, I set in the options to play all videos. Not an elegant solutions but good enough for now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.top-carousel').bxSlider({
  onSliderLoad: function(){
 jQuery('video').trigger('play');
  },
  onSlideAfter: function(){
   // jQuery('video').trigger('play');
  }
});
});
```