# Stop Videos from autoplay on load - BXSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I am using bxslider for a simple video slider in one of my sites. But the all the videos in the slider starts playing on load. I would have to disable that.

**HTML:**

```
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <?php 
    foreach($vdos->result() as $vdo){
      ?>
      <li>
        <iframe src="<?php echo asset_url().'vdo/'.$vdo->vdoPath; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
      </li>
      <?php
    }
    ?>
  </ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      video: true,
      useCSS: false,
      auto: false,
      controls: false,
      onSliderLoad: function(){
       slider.stopAuto(true);
     }
   });
```

I have been stuck on it for a while now. Any guidance would be very helpful.

I tired the solution posed

[bxslider stopping video element autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643232/bxslider-stopping-video-element-autoplay?rq=1)

It didn't work out for me.
Thank you.

P.S: I am testing with .mp4 format

Comment: the solution didn't work because  `iframe` of why you are using iframe for loading videos?? i think it's hard to modify on iframe

Comment: I just implemented as prescribed by the plugin. http://bxslider.com/examples/video

Comment: [IFrame contentDocument Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp), here they show how to access the content DOM on a iframe, but the cross domain could prove to be problematic...
I solve something like that requesting the content on server side and serving it to my web...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is `iframe`

```
<ul class="bxslider" >
  <li>
     <video preload="" loop="" class="video-bg">
            <source src="video/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
  </li>
  <li>
     <video preload="" loop="" class="video-bg">
            <source src="video/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
  </li>
</ul>



$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    video: true,
    useCSS: false,
    onSliderLoad:function(currentIndex){
        $("video").trigger("play");
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suppose this should be updated in the plugins docs as well.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with iframes. How does this resolve OP's issue?

Comment: @zer00nethe question is, why the code is not working for user. and answer: the problem is `iframe` . i put the code to show the user that this codes works fine